# In Netlogo, can you add lists together?

Tags: netlogo

I have multiple lists (10 in total) of the same length that have to be added together.

eg. [1 2 3 4] + [1 1 1 1] + [9 10 11 12] = [11 13 15 17]

Is there an easy way to accomplish this is Netlogo?

Answer (score 1):

The primitive you are looking for is `map`. Here is an example of how to use it to add lists together:

```
to testme
  let l1 [1 2 3 4]
  let l2 [3 4 5 6]
  let l3 [5 6 7 8]
  let l4 (map + l1 l2 l3)
  print l4
end
```